# Go : assignment to entry in nil map

Tags: go, runtime-error, goroutine

When trying to set value to the `map`(`countedData`) in the below code, I am getting an error that says, `assignment to entry in nil map`.

```
func receiveWork(out <-chan Work) map[string][]ChartElement {

    var countedData map[string][]ChartElement

    for el := range out {
        countedData[el.Name] = el.Data
    }
    fmt.Println("This is never executed !!!")

    return countedData
}
```

`Println` does not execute (as the error occurs on a lien before that).

There are some goroutines , that are sending data to channel, and `receiveWork` method should be making a map like this:

```
map =>
    "typeOne" => 
       [
         ChartElement,
         ChartElement,
         ChartElement,
       ],
    "typeTwo" => 
       [
         ChartElement,
         ChartElement,
         ChartElement,
       ]
```

Please help me fix the error.

Comment: Looks like your channel passed into `receiveWork` never closes. You need to make sure it closes in order for the for loop to end.

Comment: It ends up, in main function, when all goroutines done their work, and writing to the out channel is finished.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Map types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> A new, empty map value is made using the built-in function make, which
>   takes the map type and an optional capacity hint as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(map[string]int)
> make(map[string]int, 100)
> ```
>
> The initial capacity does not bound its size: maps grow to accommodate
>   the number of items stored in them, with the exception of nil maps. A
>   nil map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be
>   added.

You write:

```
var countedData map[string][]ChartElement
```

Instead, to initialize the map, write,

```
countedData := make(map[string][]ChartElement)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a composite literal:

```
countedData := map[string][]ChartElement{}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals